# Pandas - count streak since last value change

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to get the streak since a value in a specific column changed:

```
datetime                 val1          val2  val1-streak   val2-streak
2018-04-01 00:00:00        4           1        0             0
2018-05-01 00:00:00        5           2        0             0
2018-06-01 00:00:00        5           2        1             1
2018-07-01 00:00:00        6           2        0             2
2018-08-01 00:00:00        7           2        0             3
2018-09-01 00:00:00        7           3        1             0
2018-10-01 00:00:00        7           3        2             1
2018-11-01 00:00:00        5           2        0             0
```

For now it is ok to assume that the dattime column is equaly spaced. That way i can just count the "periods" since the value in a target column changed. Ideally the function can additionally count the difference in datetinme since the value changed last.

I found a few solutions on this site but when i looked more closely they did not really describe my problem:

[Pandas - count since last transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52494999/pandas-count-since-last-transaction)

[Counting changes in pandas row values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918038/counting-changes-in-pandas-row-values)

[In pandas, how do you find the time since a column by value changes, when grouped by another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752580/in-pandas-how-do-you-find-the-time-since-a-column-by-value-changes-when-groupe)

[Pythonic way to calculate streaks in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397647/pythonic-way-to-calculate-streaks-in-pandas-dataframe)

[finding streaks in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427298/finding-streaks-in-pandas-dataframe)

https://joshdevlin.com/blog/calculate-streaks-in-pandas/

.... at least I was not able to transfer the given answers to my problem.

Comment: why is "val2-streak" `0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0`? shouldn't it be `0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0`, since it changes from 1 to 2 in the second row?

Comment: Yes you are correct, i added a few rows to show the inteded behaviour, as it can also happend the values that where previously encountered can show up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom function for generate counter by consecutive values by compare differencies per columns specified in list by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), compare for not equal by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with cumulative sum, last pass to [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
vals = ['val1','val2']

def f(x):
    x = x.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
    return x.groupby(x).cumcount()

df = df.join(df[vals].apply(f).add_suffix('_streak'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with how to do it with a single column. First off we need to find each point where the value changes:

```
diffs = df['val1'].diff(1)
change_points = diffs != 0
```

Since previously encountered values can show up again we need to find a proper way to distinguish different streaks of the same value. We'll achieve that with a cumulative sum of the change point array. For ease we'll create a temporary DataFrame to hold those results (you can create a new column in your dataframe, but that's a bit messy)

```
change_points_cumsum = change_points.cumsum()
tmp_merged = pd.concat([serie, change_points_cumsum], axis=1, keys=['val1', 'change_points_cumsum'])
```

Every streak is assigned a different `change_points_cumsum` value so now a simple group by and cumulative count can be applied to get the final result

```
tmp_merged["val1-streak"] = tmp_merged.groupby(change_points_cumsum).cumcount()
print(tmp_merged)

   val1  change_points_cumsum  val1-streak 
0     4                     1             0
1     5                     2             0
2     5                     2             1
3     6                     3             0
4     7                     4             0
5     7                     4             1
6     7                     4             2
7     5                     5             0
```

If you are looking for a shorter, more compact solution

```
change_points_cumsum = df['val1'].diff(1).ne(0).cumsum()
change_points_cumsum.groupby(change_points_cumsum).cumcount()

0    0
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    2
7    0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I also really liked this Answer. And it would also solve my problem. I can not mark two answers as correct i think.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try the following:

(i) Create a stacked Series using `set_index` + `unstack` (this is to use not repeat the same function on two columns separately).

(ii) Use `groupby` + `diff` to find differences among consecutive elements: `tmp`

(iii) We're interested in the location where the differences are 0; we do another `groupby` + `cumsum` to get the desired outcome.

(iv) Use `pivot` to get the output back into the shape of `df`.

```
tmp = df.set_index('datetime')[['val1','val2']].unstack().groupby(level=0).diff()
df[['val1-streak','val2-streak']] = pd.pivot(tmp.eq(0)
                                             .groupby([tmp.index.get_level_values(0), 
                                                       tmp.ne(0).cumsum()])
                                             .cumsum()
                                             .reset_index(), 
                                             'datetime', 'level_0', 0).to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
              datetime  val1  val2  val1-streak  val2-streak
0  2018-04-01 00:00:00     4     1            0            0
1  2018-05-01 00:00:00     5     2            0            0
2  2018-06-01 00:00:00     5     2            1            1
3  2018-07-01 00:00:00     6     2            0            2
4  2018-08-01 00:00:00     7     2            0            3
5  2018-09-01 00:00:00     7     3            1            0
6  2018-10-01 00:00:00     7     3            2            1
7  2018-11-01 00:00:00     5     2            0            0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I also really liked this Answer as it gave me the idea to use the information i get when applying diff() to calculated values like mean increase /decrease and mean lenght of the streak. And it would also solve my problem. I can not mark two answers as correct i think.